# Linq to Sql Udf call faster than plain Ado.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, ado.net

We have a legacy application where we are calling a User Defined Function in database. This Udf returns a very large xml string (about 1971540 chars). It is quite surprising that linq to sql's **ExecuteMethodCall** runs very fast, while plain Ado.Net DbDataReader.GetString() is slow!!!

We have benched marked the calls and L2S can fetch it in under 4 seconds, while plain Ado.net DbDataReader.GetString() fetches it in about 37 seconds.

Looking into the L2S code it seems to be using same DbDataReader.GetString() method, albeit through dynamically generated IL code. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Linq/SqlClient/Reader/ObjectReaderCompiler.cs,b2f6633a6c502138

I would like to understand what enables L2S to read such a huge data in so less time?

Note that it runs fast enough even in first call, so it probably is not caching magic.

**Edit**

```
using (DbConnection con = _dataContext.Database.Connection)
{
    DbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.Transaction = _dataContext.Database.CurrentTransaction.UnderlyingTransaction;

    parameters.Cast<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter>().ToList().ForEach(x => cmd.Parameters.Add(x));
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 500;

    if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        con.Open();
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess | System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleResult | System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            var data = reader.GetString(0);

            sw.Stop();
            var et = sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        }
    }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: That would be open to debate, since no code exist for us to properly handle said occurrence.

Comment: @Greg I know without exact Database and code it will be difficult to verify, but I'm hopping I'm not the first person to face this issue.

Comment: In my experience, Linq to Sql is often significantly slower than `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: @Greg Yes, that should have been the case since L2S is ultimately using SqlDataReader as I pointed out. It also seems they are using same method we are using to populating the data "GetString()".

Comment: Since this is a single row single column LOB result L2S overhead is near zero. There's just nothing to do for L2S. Post the code that you used to read the value.

Comment: I just added a code snippet.

Comment: Reading code is fine. CPU on the client should be near zero. Capture both queries with SQL Profiler and post everything you captured for comparison here.

Comment: @usr Sql query in SQL profiler generated by L2S looks somewhat like this: SELECT [dbo].[functionname](@p0, @p1) as [Value]. This is the sql I've used in ADO.net too.

Comment: Then capture both actual execution plans using the profiler Showplan XML event and post them as images here.

Comment: @usr both execution plans are identical (at least visually). It makes sense, since both queries are identical.

Comment: This is very strange. From your sample code, you are starting your stopwatch **after** you have issued the `reader.Read()` command, which means that the sql server will already have executed the statement. So all the hard work has already been done, and I would expect the time to execute the `reader.GetString(0)` command to be closer to 37 milliseconds than 37 seconds !

Comment: @sgmoore how funny, I didn't notice that. The benchmark is invalid. But query results can be streamed. It is not the case that Read always does all work. Depends on the query plan and data shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after lots of pondering and tweaking... It turned out to be issue with **MARS** configuration!!

MARS was turned on in our latest refactored code (I think default behavior of EF) where as it wasn't present in Linq to sql connection string.

Once we remove the "MultipleActiveRecordSets=True;" from connection string it works fine. Not sure why removing MARS works though.

Hopefully it will help someone facing similar issue in future.